# Want to Change the Magento go header section

Tags: css, xml, magento, php

Currently I'm working on magento go. Its not just like Other magento CMS. Its a online CMS where I can manage my store. I need to change the home page design. I have tried to edit CSS files but it doesn't give me the desired output. I want to change the whole page design and want to add my one. Basically I don't get the way to edit the header part. The built in header editing section is known to me but I want to change the whole header part. Am I permit to do this in magento go? I have the html and css file but can not integrated the file in magento go. Is there any solution? Is there any place in magento go to edit phtml file? I need it very badly.Please HELP.

Thanks
Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great video series called Magento Community Tutorials on how to customize every aspect of Magento. Link below:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3B0BAAF482B16EAB

However, as I only have the community edition, I am not sure if you can access Magento's server for Magento Go to customize to the level that you can with the Community edition.

Are you able to access all of the files and folders of Magento Go?  For example, can you access the server's root folder and see something like this:

[image]

If you can, then the video tutorial series will answer all of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that works. The videos you gave are for magento community version, where you can actually access the FTP of your webhost. Magento go is "server-based" you cannot access the ftp files. I've been having the same problem as pavan.

But I had some level of success in changing some properties in the header portion... well, Header-container actually.

In your CSS Editor, type these code:

`.header-container { 
    background: #FF6666`}

This changes the color of your header to a rosy red color. Change the background value to your desired color.

with the other elements, I'm still looking for their classnames, here are some changes I made in my header

```
.top-cart .block-title strong { 
display:block; 
padding-right:10px; 
background: url(../images/bkg_header-panel.gif) 100% -71px no-repeat ; 
font-size:10px; 
color:#565051; 
font-weight:bold; 
text-decoration:none; }
```

this changed the color of my cart(#) text.

I know this is not much but I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Here is a new way I just found. This method allows you to put a picture in your header portion. btw, If you are using a background color (like I showed below/above), i'd advice you use a transparent bg on your pictures.

1. upload your picture. Go to Design > Themes Editor > CSS Editor. Click on the Manage button next to **Image Assets**. Click Browse then look select the picture you want on your header. Then click Upload.
2. Insert your CSS rules for your Header. The header portion is usually named **header-container**. So we need to make a css code for this. Type:

   .header-container {background: url() ;}

You can add some more options in your background property in CSS. For more information in CSS, try [CSS Background Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) from w3schools.com

1. Place your image in your CSS rules. This time, we need to place the "image code" in your CSS rule. Place your cursor between the brackets "()" then Click Manage button in your **Image Assets**, select the image you uploaded (or the image you want to put in your header) then click Insert File

Again. I hope this helps.